# VLC remote for Android with huge Play/Pause button

Tags: android, remote-access, dark-theme, vlc

I watch movies with VLC running on my laptop, and want to play/pause using my Android.
All VLC remotes that I have found have a moderately-sized Play/Pause button:

[image: VLC remote]

My use case is that I watch a movie in relative darkness, and I only need to pause/play whenever I need to go to the door or grab a drink. I don't need to change the volume or fast-forward or open a different movie or anything. On the opposite, I want to avoid these features as I might press them by mistake.

So, I want a HUGE Play/Pause button.
Ideally, no other buttons on the whole screen.

Must be gratis, dark background.

Comment: With "VLC remote" you mean VLC is running on your computer, and you want to control it from your Android device, I assume? If so, while waiting for the perfect answer, be welcome to check my list for that: [Remote control VLC](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_mediaplayer#group_662). [VLC Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hobbyistsoftware.android.vlcremote_usfree) seems to offer a widget coming pretty close to your needs.

Comment: @Izzy: I hope it is clearer now. VLC Remote is actually the one screenshotted above :-/

Comment: Uh – you didn't say that. Have you tried its widget? I've never used any such app, so I cannot say for sure – but one of the screenshots at Play look like the widget might at least fit *better* (not perfectly, unfortunately).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with MATRIC Android app. It's free when you use it for up to 6 buttons and it's full customizable. Check it out https://matricapp.com/

[image]